# Upgrading to MySQLi - As easy as swapping out mysql for mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After a lot of responses on a number of different posts I've seen, I'm stopping using mysql and am trying to upgrade my site to use mysqli.

My question is, based on the functions of mysql that I list below (which are the ones I currently use) can I do a blanket replace on 'mysql_' for 'mysqli_' and not break functionality? I've already done some research on each of these functions and none of the mysqli versions look like they wouldn't work, but I just need to be sure before I swap them all out.

query

fetch_array

connect

select_db

error

real_escape_string

num_rows

fetch_assoc

free_result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli) which provides answers to at least most of your functions.

For example:

- `mysql_connect` will be replaced by [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php)
- `mysql_error` will be replaced by [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and/or [`mysqli_connect_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php), depending on the context
- `mysql_query` will be replaced by [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!