# Conversion from MySQL to mysqli not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert-id

I am in a process of converting my Existing MySQL to mysqli

But I can't get this piece of code correct

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sendmsg`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body` , `mdate`, `mtime`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime')");
$new_id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `recievemsg`(`msgid`, `sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`, `mdate`, `mtime`, `status`) VALUES ($new_id,'$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime','UNREAD')");
```

What I tried is given below but didn't work

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `sendmsg`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body` , `mdate`, `mtime`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime')");
$new_id = mysqli_insert_id();
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `recievemsg`(`msgid`, `sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`, `mdate`, `mtime`, `status`) VALUES ($new_id,'$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime','UNREAD')");
```

The Problem is with the `$new_id = mysqli_insert_id();` statement bcoz the first query is executing

Comment: Since you're upgrading to `mysqli`, you should take the time to familiarise yourself with parameter binding and prepared statements.

Comment: Procedural style `mysqli_*` functions need the connection variable passed into them, unlike `mysql_*` or the object orientated version of `mysqli`

Comment: Could you provide me a link to detailed tutorial on how to convert from mysql to mysqli.. I couldnt get a good one

Comment: the [PHP manual](http://php.net/mysqli) has everything you'll need to know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mysqli Object oriented style to get the last inserted id use this

```
$mysqli->insert_id ;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

So your queries will be as

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `sendmsg`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body` , `mdate`, `mtime`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime')");

$new_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `recievemsg`(`msgid`, `sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`, `mdate`, `mtime`, `status`) VALUES ($new_id,'$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime','UNREAD')");
```

Comment: So i just need to insert it at the end of second query? How will it get inserted in the appropriate coloumn.. If you aren't busy could you pls rewrite the queries i provided

Comment: so after the first query get the last inserted id and use it on the 2nd query.