# Get first name from current session PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

So its the final step of a college project...
i'm trying to get a value from a mysql table dependant from the session.
For example, you enter your email and password, the next page you are redirected two has your first name.
I'm using this script for the login check:

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   $host="localhost";
   $username="***"; 
   $password="***";  
   $db_name="***"; 
   $tbl_name="usersWebsite";

   mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

   $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
   $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

   $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
   $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
   $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);

   $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($count==1){
      session_register("myusername");
      session_register("mypassword"); 
      header("location:login_success.php");
   }
   else {
      echo "Wrong Username or Password";
   }
   ob_end_flush();
?>
```

and i'm using this short code to create the session:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
        header("location:main_login.php");
    }
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://starkwave.com/main/dashboard" />
```

got the code on an tutorial online and adapted it to my situation 
i want to echo in a php page the first name of the user that logged in,
Thank you very much

Comment: `mysql_`is deprecated plz switch to `mysqli_` look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli

Comment: `session_register` is also deprecated. Where you got that legacy code from :-S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_register()` and `session_unregister()` will no longer work in future so don't use them. Use

```
    $_SESSION['myusername']='give your name';
```

when you checked if user exists in database then use like this

```
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);


        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($count==1){
            $data= mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['usernmae']=$data['name_in_database'];/* put here name of column in database*/
            header("location:login_success.php");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
```

and when you want to print name just use

```
        echo  $_SESSION['usernmae'];
```

Comment: Additionaly mysql_* are also deprecated so better use pdo or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

To echo the name of the user registered in the session, just read the saved variable in the current session:

```
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
```

Comment: You can't access like this without setting it first

Comment: On his code is already set 
    session_register("myusername");

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the session you register the string "myusername", not the variable $myusername, holding the actual username.

You can do $_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;

Answer (score 0):

First you must add user's first name to the session when you is authenticated
e.g.

```
if($count==1){
      session_register("myusername");
      session_register("mypassword"); 
      $_SESSION['firstName'] = "abc"; // set the first name that you get from form or somewhere else
      header("location:login_success.php");
   }
```

Then you can `echo $_SESSION['firstName']` from where you want