# PHP fails to insert into Mysql (auto increment)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, post

---

I have made my Mysql Table link this:

[image]
[image]

That problem occurs because i am not able to insert auto_increment into my mysql query.

`index.php`

```
<?php

        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $description=$_POST["description"];
        $image=$_POST["image"];
        $amount=$_POST["amount"];

 $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `store`(`id`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `image`) VALUES (NULL,'".$name."','".$description."','".$amount."','".$image."')");




?>
```

I post to it by a HTML form and it does executes the query but i get no rows in that table. I thnk its because of auto_increment or Unique or Primary. i was told to use `NULL` in place of auto_increment value but it doesn't work.

Any Help?

P.S Noob here!

EDIT:
error is:

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\xampp\htdocs\Html\Home\index.php on line 9

Comment: `VALUES ('','".$name."',`

Comment: Don't use mysql_query in new code, it's all but deprecated.  Also, don't build query strings from user input, your application will be wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Since you're not doing this... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Plus, you sure you're connected?

Comment: @AsheshKumar There you go, use `mysqli_` functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I provided all information. Then why Downvote?

Comment: Even better [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: Oops sorry, I pressed the wrong key lol! my bad. So the problem is with your MySQL API. See links above, that should fix it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Any other way?

Comment: Other way to what? Far as I'm concerned, you have to switch your `mysql_` with `mysqli_` - notice the `i`? It stands for "improved".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62834/discussion-between-ashesh-kumar-and-fred-ii).

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat, I have to leave.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Any instruction on How to deactivate Mysql and setup mysqli connection ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli and the links in the answers. I really have to go, I'm late enough as it is. Will be back later, if I can help then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the Issue of mysql_query being deprecated, I recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. It's super easy and much safer with prepared staements. This snippet will provide a connection to the DB to make your queries:

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_db = "my_database";
$mysql_user = "my_user";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$mysql_host.';dbname='.$mysql_db.';charset=utf8', $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
```

Once you have that on your page, you can use `$db` to interact with your database.

```
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `store` (`name`, `description`, `price`, `image`) VALUES (:name, :desc, :amt, :img)");
$q->execute(array(":name"=>$name, ":desc"=>$description, ":amt"=>$amount, ":img"=>$image));
```

Also, for auto-imcrement values, you can omit that field all together.

PS, there's a stntax error. You're missing a space before the opening parenthesis:
`store (`

Comment: Accepted for stating easiest way to make  DB connection and also pointing syntax error

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `id` column from your query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `store`(`name`, `description`, `price`, `image`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$description."','".$amount."','".$image."')");
```

Comment: @AsheshKumar Read the comments under your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert `NULL` into a `AUTO_INCREMENT` field! It will automaticly fill in this field, so make the query without the `id`!

UPDATE!

As far as i know best practice is PDO so i would suggest you to change to PDO!

Also you have to make a connection first! (DB_HOST and so on are constants! you can change this to variables if you want)

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Then try this:

```
<?php

    $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `store`(`name`, `description`, `price`, `image`)
                                            VALUES (':name',':description',':amount',':image')");

    $statement->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
    $statement->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
    $statement->bindParam(':amount', $_POST['amount']);
    $statement->bindParam(':image', $_POST['image']);

    $statement->execute();

?>
```

Comment: dont forget strip_tags()!

Comment: @AsheshKumar updated it! Try the new one, also i would suggest you to escape your POST! $connenction is you connection variable.

Comment: @Rizier123 Why i have to pass to $connection ?

Comment: @AsheshKumar Its optional but it specifies the MySQL connection.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: @Rizier123 Now this! `
Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\xampp\htdocs\Html\Home\index.php on line 4`

Comment: @Rizier123 and this `
Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\xampp\htdocs\Html\Home\index.php on line 10"

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'id' from values into your query

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `store`(`name`, `description`, `price`, `image`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$description."','".$amount."','".$image."')");
```

AUTO_INCREMENT works by itself ;)

Comment: Not Working Please help

Comment: print the error using mysql_query( ) or die (mysql_error())

Answer (score -2):

you don't need a single quote or an apostrophe to enclose column names, since these data don't replace with variables. apostrophes need when we want to replace columns with data, here in values.