# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource error at android

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send userid and otp which is entered in an edittext in an android app but from server side i get following response.

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   **/nfs/c07/h02/mnt/111018/domains/surun.co/html/demo/rest/api.php**
>   on line **168**

line no 168 from php code

```
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
```

The php code in more details follows:

```
 public function selectQuery($table_name,$fields,$where="",$show = 0)

    {

       $i =0;

       if($where == "")

       $sql = "SELECT  ".$fields." FROM ".$table_name;

       else

       $sql = "SELECT  ".$fields." FROM ".$table_name." WHERE ".$where;

      //MySqli Select Query

      if($show == 1)

      return $sql;

      $results = mysql_query( $sql,$this->db );

      if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)

      {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))

        {

          $result[$i++]= $row;

        }

      }

      return $result;

    }
```

Comment: I am not getting where the error or problem.actually these php is written by my friend so i am not able to slove the problem.please help

Comment: The now deprecated mysql_query method returns false on failure. So your code should be if($result && mysql_num_rows($result))

Answer (score 0):

Read this link and apply these changes [How could I change this mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli) while also adding error checking in the form of

```
 $results = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
```

(or for MySQL just use `$results = mysqli_query($sql,$this->db) or die (mysql_error());` )

What you currently have is that your `$this->db` value is not connecting the database properly or you have a syntax error in your WHERE clause.