# how to insert into multiple fields in same db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to insert a single selection into a field for multiple users.  I have the following code, when the selection is made and submit is entered.  I do not get an error, I get the next page with the message posted 5 times, which is how many users are not it the weekpicks table. But nothing is inserted into the DB.

```html
<?
// This code is to use to place info into the MySQL

$sTeam1 = $_POST['sTeam1'];

// (WHERE username FROM authorize WHERE username not in ( SELECT username FROM weekpicks WHERE whatweek='$totalnoOfWeek' )" .

//$nMemberID = (integer) Query

$sql_events = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM authorize WHERE username not in ( SELECT username FROM weekpicks WHERE whatweek='$totalnoOfWeek' )") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_events)) {
$username = $row["username"];

("INSERT INTO weekpicks SET " . "username = '" . ($username) . "'," . "date_create = NOW(), " . "whatweek = '" . ($totalnoOfWeek) . "'," . "team = '" . addslashes($sTeam1) . "'" . 'INSERT');

echo "<HTML>

            <BODY>
            <h2>Your pick of " . ($sTeam1) . ", for week " . ($totalnoOfWeek) . ", has been added.</h2>
            
            <P align=left><a href=\"nopickpolicy.php\">Return to main page</a></p>
            </BODY>
            </HTML>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, note that [**mysql_* functions are deprecated**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and removed on newer version of php. It's also worth looking at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4577762).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the string for insert but you are not running it.

Fixing your code it'd be:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_events)) {
$username = $row["username"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO weekpicks SET " . "username = '" . ($username) . "'," . "date_create = NOW(), " . "whatweek = '" . ($totalnoOfWeek) . "'," . "team = '" . addslashes($sTeam1) . "'");

//echo ...
}
```

Fixing the string syntax you could do this, which looks nicer. Also using `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `addslashes()`, since `addslashes` is not as safe as mysql's native function for php.

```
$sTeam1 = mysql_real_escape_string($sTeam1);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO weekpicks SET username = '$username', date_create = NOW(), whatweek = '$totalnoOfWeek', team = '$sTeam1');
```

Another thing I must tell you:

Stop using `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` instead.

`mysql_` was removed from PHP7 and deprecated after PHP 5.5

It's not as safe as `mysqli_`, so consider improving your code to the new model.

[Follow this guide in order to change your code properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: Whenever you need. Consider changing mysql to mysqli