# php/mysql - do that for each ID

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

first time here. I have found many useful stuff from this site, but im stuck right now.

I need help with the following code. I want this code to check every ID stats[population, populationgrowth], do the calculation which you can find in IF function and then insert result which is populationgrowth for each ID. It's a cronjob.

```
$get_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats") or die(mysql_error());
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_users)){

if($stats['population'] > $stats['maxpopulation']) {    
    $populationgrowth = 0;
}
else{
    $populationgrowth = 1 * ($unit['moonhut']);
}

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET populationgrowth='".$populationgrowth."' WHERE id='".$user['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the arithmetic in the SQL query:

```
UPDATE stats s    
    SET populationgrowth = (CASE WHEN population > maxpopulation THEN 0
                                 ELSE 1 * $unit['moonhut']
                            END):
```

Notes:

- `1 *` is redundant.
- Stop using mysql_.  It is no longer supported.
- Then, use parameters in your queries for safer queries.

Comment: Here is a good place to start for mysqli_:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that in future.