# How to solve this error [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()] in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone suggest how to solve this error in php "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" ? I am using php 7.0.4 and php extension is mysqli.

Comment: you are trying to connect by using mysql_connect() instade of mysqli_connect().

you are saying you had extension for mysqli then you should go for mysqli_connect().

Comment: [Searched the website yet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35025964/4982088)? Has been answered dozens of times. I only raise my eyebrow that you think that mysql**i** refers to this error.

Comment: I have changed the mysql_connect() function to mysqli_connect() but it is showing the same error.

Comment: That means you need to enable the extensions in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to connect by using mysql_connect() instade of mysqli_connect().

you are saying you had extension for mysqli then you should go for mysqli_connect().

Answer (score 0):

You are using a PHP function that was removed on PHP 7

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

use mysqli_connect() instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php