# Abbreviated days like MWF, TThS (This are my class schedules)

Tags: php, mysql

Need help on this: in my sql table I have this Schedule and is written in MWF, TThS, Sun. I want it to be filtered so that only the schedule for today will be the output...e.g Today is Tuesday so TThS schedule is being outputted. Hope you could help me.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: i dont really have any idea on how to do it... :(

Comment: e.g. MWF = ("Monday","Wednesday","Friday")

Comment: Can't you store the days in two letters instead? If days would be stored in Mo - Tu - We - Th - Fr - Sa - Su format it would be much easier to query it - a simple LIKE would have been enough.

Comment: It's a class schedule and in I am using the school's database as my database. I can't really change it :( someone told me that i could use an array...but I'm really at the edge right now :3

Comment: whoever designed that database really needs to read up on how to set up Databases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the way your schedules times are stored is that you can't do a simple [`LIKE %T%`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), as it would get schedules for `Th` as well.

A possible solution would be to use [MySQL REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) for the specific cases of Tuesday (`T` not followed by `h`) and Saturday (`S` not followed by `un`).

Basically you would build an array of the where clauses that should be used depends of the week day:

```
$where_date_clauses = array(
    1 => 'LIKE "M%"',
    2 => 'REGEXP "T(?!h)"',
    3 => 'LIKE "%W%"',
    4 => 'LIKE "%Th%"',
    5 => 'LIKE "%F%"',
    6 => 'REGEXP "S(?!un)"',
    7=> 'LIKE "%Sun"'
);
```

The regexp here use the negative lookahead pattern - it will match only if the character is not immediately followed by the lookahead content.

And then build your query like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM schedules_table WHERE schedule ' . $where_date_clauses[date('N')];
```

Where [`date('N')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) return the number of the week day.

***Side note***

Here is an example of how to set up your query using PDO:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=your_db_name;host=your_db_host', 'mysql_user_name', 'mysql_user_password');
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM block_subject2 where id_number = ? ORDER BY timed DESC LIMIT 1');
    $sth->execute(array(
        (int) $_SESSION['stud_id']
    ));
    $row = $sth->fetch();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to DB: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: is it compatible with what i am using right now? im using simple php codes...

$result8=mysql_query("select * from block_subject2 where id_number='$_SESSION[stud_id]' AND day='$where_date_clauses[date('N')]' ORDER BY timed DESC limit 1");

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM schedules_table WHERE schedule ' . $where_date_clauses[date('N')];

how can i convert it to a code such as this>

$result8=mysql_query("select * from block_subject2 where id_number='$_SESSION[stud_id]' AND day='$where_date_clauses[date('N')]' ORDER BY timed DESC limit 1");

coz it aint working :(

Comment: You should not use the `=` operator in your query - the operator is built in the `$where_date_clauses` array (`LIKE`, `REGEXP`). Look at the query I wrote as example.

Comment: By the way, you should avoid using `mysql_query` as it has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and will be removed in PHP 7. You should better use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: so how am I going to convert this > $result8=mysql_query("select * from block_subject2 where id_number='$_SESSION[stud_id]' ORDER BY timed DESC limit 1");
   while($row8=mysql_fetch_array($result8))
    { 
to PDO? any idea?

Comment: I updated my answer to add an example of how to use PDO for your query. I suggest you to give some read to the [`PDO::construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) documentation to understand how it works.

Comment: OMG! all of my codes are in that form :( it would take me forever to edit my codes...and my thesis defense is next week :(

Comment: @KenPaulMiñozaBahinting That's allright if it's working using mysql_* function, keep it that way. But I suggest to notice in your thesis that you're aware that you're using deprecated code. Or, you can try to change to mysqli_* which syntax is almost the same as mysql_* functions - it's the same function but prefixed with mysqli instead of mysql, and you need to send the connector object to most of the functions. [How to change mysql to mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli)