# Convert registration form from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my registration form in mysql and i'm trying to convert it to mysqli so that it would work with the data base

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  

    mysql_select_db("Project"); 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
      $FirstName =$_POST['FirstName'];  
      $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];  
      $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];  
      $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];  
      $PassWord = $_POST['PassWord'];  
      $Email = $_POST['Email'];  
      $CourseID = $_POST['CourseID']; 

    if($FirstName==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        FirstName!')</script>"; 
        exit(); 
    } 
    if($LastName==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        LastName!')</script>"; 
        exit(); 
    } 
    if($DOB==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        DOB!')</script>"; 
        exit(); 
    } 
    if($UserName==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        UserName!')</script>"; 
        exit(); 
    } 
    if($PassWord==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        PassWord!')</script>"; 
        exit(); 
    } 

    if($CourseID==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        CourseID!')</script>"; 

        exit(); 
    } 
    if($Email==''){ 
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your  
        Email!')</script>"; 
        exit(); 
    } 
    $check_email = "select * FROM Student WHERE Email='$Email'"; 

    $run = mysql_query($check_email); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){ 
       echo "<script> alert('email $Email already exist in our database, 
       please try another one')</script>"; 
       exit();            
    } 
    $query = "insert into Student (FirstName,LastName,DOB,UserName, 
    PassWord,Email,CourseID) VALUES('$FirstName','$LastName','$DOB', 
    '$UserName','$PassWord','$Email','$CourseID')"; 
    if(mysql_query($query)){ 

        echo "<script> window.open('Welcome.php','_self')</script>"; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're trying the important thing to answer is **what have you tried**. It's good you're switching, but the problem here is not clear. Most `mysqli` calls are very similar, but one thing to pay particular attention to is using **prepared statements**.

Comment: in addition to what @tadman said, there is the [php manual that have examples for the functions you need to convert from mysql to mysqli...](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) Aside from the fact you did not seem to even try to search your issue around... [How could I change this mysql to mysqli?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-could-i-change-this-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: There's a whole section in the documentation on this, especially about [using prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 3):

Change wherever necessary. This is OOP approach. Also donot store plain password.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","db_name");
$check_email = $db->prepare("select * FROM Student WHERE Email=?"); 
$check_email->bind_param("s",$email);
$check_email->execute();
$result=$check_email->get_result();
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();

       if($row)
{
               echo "<script> alert('email $Email already exist in our database, 
               please try another one')</script>"; 
               exit();            
 } 
            $query = $db->prepare("insert into Student (FirstName,LastName,DOB,UserName, 
            PassWord,Email,CourseID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

            $query->bind_param("sssssss",$firstname,$lastname,$dob,$username,$password,$email,$courseid);          

if($query->execute())
{ 

                echo "<script> window.open('Welcome.php','_self')</script>"; 
            }
```

Comment: Wish I could give you more credit for recommending the OOP style. That makes mistakes a lot harder. Watch you don't quote values, like on line 3 here.

Comment: `$db->prepare("select * FROM Student WHERE Email='?'")` is wrong. You're quoting the placeholder.