# Updating from MySQL to MySQLi issues with pulling data from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm looking to update this from MySQL to MySQLi But I keep encountering errors while doing so.
Basically this is a chunk of code for my dynamic page created from a link on another page.

```html
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Password');
$select_db = mysql_select_db('playerslog');

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['UUID']);
//Remove LIMIT 1 to show/do this to all results.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `playerslog` WHERE `UUID` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// Echo page content
```

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this? Thanks for your time!

Update as requested.

```html
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Password');
$select_db = mysqli_select_db('playerslog');


$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['UUID']);
//Remove LIMIT 1 to show/do this to all results.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `playerslog` WHERE `UUID` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1';
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// Echo page content

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: you're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` calls, are you aware of that?

Comment: Sorry that is left over from my attempt to do so.

Comment: 'I actually view that before posting and it didn't seem to work' - so show the results of doing the process it suggests and perhaps we can help from there.

Comment: It was just a blank page.. the file that is putting the link in the URL is completely MySQLi, it just doesn't seem to work on this page.

Comment: if you're using `mysqli_query` and co., please edit your post to reflect it. It just causes confusion this way.

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply replace mysql_* with mysqli_*. They have different syntaxes.
You should for example fix how you execute the query. Mysqli expects two parameters: the connection and then the query. You pass just the query:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Password');
$select_db = mysqli_select_db('stats');
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['UUID']);
//Remove LIMIT 1 to show/do this to all results.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `playerslog` WHERE `UUID` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// Echo page content

?>
```