# How to count MySQL connections using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was using following php code to check number of MySQL connections

```
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","$mysql_user","$mysql_pwd");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  { echo "NO CONNECTION"; }
  else
  {
unset ($result);
$result = mysql_list_processes($connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$mysql_data[]=$row["db"];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
$n_connections=count($mysql_data)-1;
}
echo "$n_connections";
```

Since mysql_connect was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, I changed $connection with

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","$mysql_user","$mysql_pwd", "$mysql_db");
```

After doing this change, $n_connections is no more returning the correct value , what is wrong in the code please ?

Thank you

note : function mysqli_list_processes in php.net does not help, I tried it and it does not work.

note 2: this post is not a duplicate of "How to change mysql to mysqli?" , my problem is replacing "$result = mysql_list_processes($connection);"

Comment: you need to change `mysql_*` every-where not in just one line

Comment: If I change mysql_list_processes with mysqli_list_processes it returns error.

Comment: There's what looks like useful input here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-processes.php (see the user comment at the bottom).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: function mysqli_list_processes does not help, I tried it and it does not work. It's not a duplicate of "How to change mysql to mysqli?" , my problem is replacing  "$result = mysql_list_processes($connection);"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply try this query

```
show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

[image: result from phpmyadmin]

Answer (score 0):

this should solve the problem and return the correct number of DB connections.

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","$mysql_user","$mysql_pwd", "$mysql_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  { echo "NO CONNECTION"; }
  else
  {

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST")) {
    $n_connections=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
 $n_connections=$n_connections-1;
}
}
echo "$n_connections";
```