# MySql connect. What to do?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

I am really new to php and I am trying to use simple insert to my mysql database from the form.

I know that this mysql connection/insertion is dangerous and not used anymore. so can anyone please help me with this simple thing? I tried to google, but nothing is working so far :/

```
<? 
$text=$_POST['name']; 
$text=$_POST['surename'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "db_name", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (name, surename)
VALUES (NOW(), '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($surename)."')");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());     
}
?>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: *"I know that this mysql connection/insertion is dangerous and not used anymore"* then start learning useful and secure tools ! Documentation: [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) | [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Don't waste your time.

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use PDO or `mysqli_*`. and learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Your query uses the variables called `$name` and `$surename`. But I can't see where you define those. Also, possibly related, you assign POST values to `$text` twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

```
$text=$_POST['name']; 
$text=$_POST['surename'];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$surename = $_POST['surename'];
```

PS: And also your column names don't match your values. Your query, after inserting params

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (name, surename) VALUES (NOW(), '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($surename)."')"
```

will probably look like this

```
INSERT INTO `table` (name, surename) VALUES (NOW(), 'Jhon', 'Wick')
```

As you can see there's `name, surename` (which probably should be `surname`) and `(NOW(), 'Jhon', 'Wick')`. So either add a column (if you have that column in your database):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (created_at, name, surename) VALUES (NOW(), 'Jhon', 'Wick')
```

or remove `NOW()` from your values

```
INSERT INTO `table` (name, surename) VALUES ('Jhon', 'Wick')
```