# How can i change this MySQL Script to MySQLI?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can i change this MySql to MySqli?

```
<?php

    // Name of the file
    $filename = 'output.sql';
    // MySQL host
    $mysql_host = 'localhost';
    // MySQL username
    $mysql_username = 'root';
    // MySQL password
    $mysql_password = 'pass';
    // Database name
    $mysql_database = 'wp_wordpress';

    // Connect to MySQL server
    mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
    // Select database
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

    // Temporary variable, used to store current query
    $templine = '';
    // Read in entire file
    $lines = file($filename);
    // Loop through each line
    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
    // Skip it if it's a comment
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
        continue;

    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;
    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
    {
        // Perform the query
        mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
        // Reset temp variable to empty
        $templine = '';
    }
    }
     echo "Data imported successfully";
    ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

this is an example

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')"))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```