# I have problem with php code connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp

I want to print all database name list that are in my wamp server mysql
and I'm getting some errors

```
 $link_id=mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"");
 $a=mysql_list_dbs($link_id);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($a))
 {
     echo $row->Database."<br>";
     }
```

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_list_dbs() in C:\wamp64\www\connection.php on line 3
>
> ( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_list_dbs() in C:\wamp64\www\connection.php on line 3

Comment: Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56997881/1839439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions, they are two different APIs. The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and should no longer be used. `mysqli_*` doesn't have an equivalent function, but you can do `mysqli_query($link_id, 'SHOW DATABASES')` and then iterate over the results. See [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for examples.

Comment: worth noting, they have been **removed** from php7

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp64\www\connection.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp64\www\connection.php on line 5

now i'm getting these errors

Comment: Sorry, procedural style would be: `mysqli_query($link_id, 'SHOW DATABASES');`

Comment: There's a dupe for this.

Comment: <shrug> I don't consider it a duplicate. The linked question doesn't tell OP how to get a database list from mysqli, which is the base issue.