# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() - WordPress Setup

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Am trying to install wordpress on nginx on windows 10, wont able to complete setup i see this after entering database connection info:

> There has been a critical error on your website.

errors from php log file

> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\nginx\html\wp\wp-admin\setup-config.php(310): wpdb->db_connect()
> #1 {main}   thrown in C:\nginx\html\wp\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1670
> [30-Aug-2020 12:55:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to
> undefined function mysqli_connect() in
> C:\nginx\html\wp\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1670

replacing mysql_connect() with mysqli_connect() in wp-db.php did not solve the problem for me

server info:

- Windows 10 Home x64-bit
- nginx 1.17.10
- php 7.4.9.0 >> VC15 x64 Non Thread Safe (2020-Aug-04 15:17:37)
- mysql 5.7.23.0

nginx config:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }
        
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
           root           html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

php-cgi is always running on 127.0.0.1:9000 before starting nginx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I tried changing mysql to mysqli did not work, i don’t know why the database is not connected even though mysql is installed and working properly, I have added php-cgi to the firewall exceptions, but there is a problem connecting to the database, I don’t know why?!

Comment: The problem is PHP, you don't have the mysql extension, php on windows is pretty annoying to setup. Try installing it from pear packages.

Comment: that's true, because there is no mysql section "phpinfo.php", which means that mysql extension is not properly installed. I'll keep digging Until I get to the solution, I'll start by installing mysql extension, although it's installed and activated through php.ini

Comment: "mysqli did not work"...how specifically? What went wrong when you tried? P.s. you can't install the old mysql_xx extension in php7, it's not supported. You need to use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, All you have to do is uncomment these lines in php.ini

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
```