# php version conversion in old project

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

my 1 old project which is on <5.2 php, the new version> 7.1. php I want to change to 1 You all need help.

```
function queryRunner($query){
 $result=mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
 return $result;
}

function countRow($result){

  return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

function rowRetriever($result){

  return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

function rowRetrieverObject($result){

  return mysql_fetch_object($result);
} 

function findLastInsertId(){

  return mysql_insert_id();
}

function simplifySpecialCharacter($data){

  return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

When I change mysql to mysqli an error occurs in the code

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","db_username","db_password");
 $db = mysql_select_db("db_name",$con);
 if(!$db)
 {
  mysql_error();
 }

db conection are as

Comment: You should examine the use of [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Why are you still using PHP 7.1? It is not supported for 2 years now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750908/8826361
As stated in this post,
  I did exactly that
Then you are working right on localhost, but online server is not working right.